# stop two columns from overlapping when resizing

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and have been trying to build a 2-column website. The code is here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9V3W/). There is a left-side menu with a right-side content area. If the window is large enough, there is no problem with the layout. However, when resizing the window to a narrow one, the content overflows to the menu area and I don't know how to fix it without making the position fixed or absolute, which I don't want to do because I want to have a footer at the end of the page. Can someone help me fix the problem? Thank you so much!

I also apologize in advance for the long code. I don't know which part lies the problem and pasted everything
html code:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="menunav">
    <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="siteLogo" class="centered" id="logo"/>
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="thispage">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>

<div id="content">
<div class="grid3">
 <article class="bucket" >
 <a href="#">
 <img src="images/baskerville1.jpg" alt=""/>
 <div class = "img-overlay">
   <h3>Monogram</h3></div>
   </a>
 </article>

<article class="bucket">
<a href="#">
<img src="images/Gastalt.png" alt=""/> 
<div class="img-overlay">
    <h3>Gastalt Composition</h3>
  </div>
</a>
</article>

<article class="bucket">
<a href="#">
<img src="images/redThread.png" alt=""/> 
<div class="img-overlay">
    <h3>The Red Thread - A Visual Book</h3>
  </div>
  </a>
</article>

<article class="bucket">
<a href="#">
<img src="images/poster copy.png" alt=""/> 
<div class="img-overlay">
    <h3>Typographic Hierarchy</h3>
  </div>
  </a>
</article>

<article class="bucket">
<a href="#">
<img src="images/Spaces.png" alt=""/> 
<div class="img-overlay">
    <h3>Living in Two Spaces</h3>
  </div>
  </a>
</article>  
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">&copy;2014</div>
</div>  

</body>
```

css code:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

*{
margin:0;
}

html, body {
margin: 0;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 1000px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
min-height: 100%;
}

#menunav {
position: fixed;
width:180px;
padding-top:80px;
height: 100%;
display: block;
margin: 0px;
}
#logo {
width: 70%;
position: static;
}
#menunav ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
#menunav a {
display: block;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
margin-top: 12px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 20px;
background-color: rgba(193,193,193,1.00);
color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
}
#menunav a:hover, #menunav a:active, #mainnav a:focus, #menunav a.thispage {
background-color: rgba(0,174,210,1.00);
color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
text-decoration: none;
}

#content {
display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
padding-left:225px;
padding-top:80px;
background-color:#fffeee;
}

.centered {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: block;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}
.bucket {
position:relative;
float: left;
margin-left: 3.2%;
margin-bottom:30px;
}

.grid3 .bucket:nth-of-type(3n+1){
margin-left: 0;
clear: left;
}

 .grid3 .bucket{
width: 31.2%;
}

.img-overlay h3 {
opacity: 1;
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
height: 20px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left:0;
color: rgba(255,254,254,1.00);
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
 }
 .img-overlay {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
bottom: 0px;
top: 0px;
opacity: 0;
overflow:hidden;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
transition: opacity 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
.bucket:hover .img-overlay {
opacity:1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.bucket img {
width: 100%;
}

#footer{
clear:both;
text-align: center;
line-height:20px;
vertical-align: middle;
}


@media screen and (max-width:740px){
/*change 3 column to 2 column*/
.grid3 .bucket:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    margin-left: 3.2%;
    clear: none;
}
.grid3 .bucket:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    margin-left: 0;
    clear: left;
}
}
```

Comment: `position: static;` <-- Why? It's by default static...

Comment: oh... good catch! it might be from a previous version of the file.

Comment: so whats your goal here? do you want the left column to be static as you scroll or do you just want the columns not to overlap?

Comment: I want the left column to not move while the content can be scrolled up and down. This seems to be the case when the window is big enough. But when gets shrank, the content area acts weird.

Comment: You can't have it both ways. If the left column is static, it'll always overlap with the right column, which isn't necessary a bad thing, you just need to make it work right i.e http://bit.ly/1cdqIbW

Comment: @EmileKumfa, Thank you! That makes sense and it indeed didn't look bad. Do you also know how I can eliminate the white space on the right of the screen when the window gets too small? Thanks!

Comment: I don't fully understand the question but I've updated your styles a bit so have a look at this and see if the white space issue persists. http://jsfiddle.net/CgGn6/

Answer (score 0):

Set `z-index:1` and set `background-color: #FFFFFF;` in #menunav

```
#menunav {
z-index: 1;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
position: fixed;
width:180px;
padding-top:80px;
height: 100%;
display: block;
margin: 0px;
}
```

Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/n9V3W/2/ working!!!

Comment: Hi Sam1604, thank you for your response. However, it doesn't solve the problem that the content scrolls horizontally when the window gets too small. Is there anyway to have it not scroll horizontally?